# How to invoke default methods with attrs python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-attrs

All,

Thank you for taking the time to try and address my question. My question is related to a specific Python package called `attrs` (https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/). I am just getting started with it and tried asking the same question on the Github page and was asked to re-direct my question here.

I am looking for documentation that describes or examples that talk about how to invoke default method when defining classes using `attrs`. Here is an example of what I am looking to do:

## Without using attrs

```
class Calculator: 
         def __init__(self, var_1: float, var_2: float): 
         """ Class initialization method
          
          :var_1: A positive integer 
          :var_2: Another positive integer 
          """ 
               self.var_1 = var_1 
               self.var_2 = var_2 
               self.sum = None

               # Invoke default method 
               self.set_sum() 
               
          def get_sum(): 
                self.var_1 + self.var_2 

           def set_sum(): 
                self.sum = self.get_sum()
```

## Using attrs

```
from attrs import define, validators
from typing import Union


@define
class Calculator: 
          var_1: float = field(validator=[validators.instance_of(float), validators.ge(0.))
          var_2: float = field(validator=[validators.instance_of(float), validators.ge(0.))
          sum: Union[float, None] = field(default=None, init=False)

          def get_sum(): 
                self.var_1 + self.var_2 

           def set_sum(): 
                self.sum = self.get_sum()
```

If I know that for every instance of Calculator class, I want the sum to be set, I would typically want to invoke the method within my `__init__` method definition. Can someone shed some light on how I can do that with `attrs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `__attrs_post_init__()` (https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=post_init#other-goodies).

According to the documentation, it handles use cases when "you want to have your class’s `__init__` method do more than just the initialization, validation, etc. that gets done for you automatically when using `@define`."

The docs show the following example:

```
@define
class C:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int = field(init=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.z = self.x + self.y

obj = C(x=1, y=2)
```

After running this code, `obj` will be initialized as `C(x=1, y=2, z=3)`. Note that `z=3` was set as the sum of `x` and `y`.

In practice, your `.__attrs_post_init__()` method will be called automatically at the end of the generated `.__init__()` method.